# Проблем в алгоритме считывания данных из файла

Tags: delphi

Проблема в том, что переменной data присваивается число(проверил через дебаггер). И на этапе присваивания ячейке массива data тоже число(не ноль). Но ячейка матрицы все равно остается нулевой. В чем может быть проблема?

`matrix` - двумерный массив
`file1` - текстовый файл(на первой строке кол-во столбцов в матрице. На 2-й и 3-й строки с числами). Файл предварительно открыт для чтения.

```
procedure fillMatrix();
var i, f, l, data : integer;
begin
  n := 0;
  f := 2;
  readln(file1, n);

  for i := 1 to f do
  begin
    for l := 1 to n do
    begin
      read(file1, data);
      matrix[n, f] := data;
    end;
    readln(file1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: почему вы пишете `matrix[n, f] := ` а не `matrix[l, i] := ` ? И где вы объявляете матрицу и ее размер?

Comment: Матрицу объявляю как глобальную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть так:

```
matrix[l, i] := data;
```

Comment: Я бы поостерегся размещать подобные ответы, не обладая полным кодом топикстартера. Тем более, что в этом случае вопрос и вовсе стоит закрыть, как "вызванный опечаткой".